# Set namespace on all files in folder and sub folders

Tags: phpstorm

I have a folder in my PhpStorm project with sub folders. The PHP classes in these folders do not have namespacing and there about 750 class files.

Is there a way in PhpStorm to set the namespace on all classes in a folder and sub folder?  I really do not want to go through each file manually.

Comment: No namespace at all (all in global namespace)? Nope, AFAIK you will have to do this manually. if you would have the namespace already and want to rename it, that is supported .. but not this one AFAIK. One of the reasons: `use` statements and figuring out what class you are possibly importing here etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find and replace on each folder for the win.